Reset sequence value with a simple SQL statement in Oracle 19c
There is a table TB_LOG which did not have a sequence so far. Sequence SEQ_LOG_ID was added for the id column ID_LOG of that tabele.
Now the proper value must be set so there are no conflicts when new entries are added with existing ones.
How can I set the sequence to the next valid value. The proper number must be determinated because the statement schould be ececuted within different schemas.
alter sequence SEQ_LOG_ID restart start with (select max(ID_LOG) from TB_LOG) + 1);
Start with expects a number but the select does not seem to work.
How can this be done otherwise?

Seemt there is no way to do this with simple sql. A PL/SQL where the value is stored within a variable seemt to be the only solution...

One option is to use a PL/SQL block.
Sequence:
SQL> create sequence seq_test;

Sequence created.

Its initial value (could be any, actually - which is probably your case):
SQL> select seq_test.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         1

PL/SQL block which first finds the MAX ID value in a table, adds 1 to it and uses the "new" value in alter sequence:
SQL> declare
  2    l_max number;
  3  begin
  4    select max(id_email_log) + 1 into l_max from email_log;
  5
  6    execute immediate 'alter sequence seq_test restart start with ' || l_max;
  7  end;
  8  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

New sequence value:
SQL> select seq_test.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
      5179

SQL>


Not exactly what I looked for but there does not seem to be another way.
